# Distributing content with app

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am creating an AR app which uses various markers using vuforia and unity.How can i bundle my markers allowing users to download them? I have no idea how to approach this problem.

Comment: Are you looking for a feature where scanning a marker downloads additional content for the game... or one where the game itself comes with markers the end user can download/print/use? Or something else? More detail would be good.

Comment: the latter one - where the game itself comes with markers the end user can download/print/use

Answer (score 0):

The way I think it´s better:

1- Create a .doc file with the markers, upload to dropbox and mark the file as public.
2- Paste the link to the file into de description of your app at Play Store and put the link into the app too.
3- Don´t forget to teach the user about using your app (as you said, download/print/use)